# Strictly define the type of a function that takes an object, modifies its values, and returns it in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'd like to create a function that makes a new object with the same keys as the original object it received but with values equal to `null`.

So...

```
function nullify(arg) {
  var returnObj = {}

  for (var key in arg) {
    returnObj[key] = null
  }

  return returnObj
}
```

I would like to add types to this function so that the TypeScript compiler will give a warning when I try to access a property that doesn't exist on the returned object. For example:

```
var nulled = nullify({
  a: 1,
  b: 2
})

console.log(nulled.foobar) // Error `foobar` doesn't exist.
```

Is something like that possible? Perhaps by using generics and `keyof`?

*Sorry, a complete TypeScript noob here*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using TS 2.1 you can use mapped types. By default a type is typically actually `type | number`. However, if you have strict checking for null objects using mapped types is the more descriptive approach.

```
type Nullified<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: null
}

function nullify<T>(arg:T) : Nullified<T> {
  var returnObj = {}

  for (var key in arg) {
    returnObj[key] = null
  }

  return returnObj
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you can then afterwards not assign anything to the properties of the object returned from the function, because the type definition of Nullified<T> enforces all the properties to be null.

Comment: @NineBerry technically you can still assign null to it, but that's fair.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using **generics** like this:

```
function nullify<T>(arg: T): T {
    var returnObj = {} as T;

    for (var key in arg) {
        returnObj[key] = null
    }

    return returnObj
}
```

Usage:

```
var nulled = nullify({
    a: 1,
    b: 2
})

console.log(nulled.a); // No problem
console.log(nulled.x); // Compiler error  Property 'x' does not exist on type '{ a: number; b: number; }'.
```

Note that you do not need to specify the generic type when calling the function. The type is automatically derived by the compiler from the argument passed to the function.

---

Extending and correcting [Paarth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42463239/101087): When using **strict null checking** and having **TypeScript 2.1 or higher** available, you might want to declare the returned type to allow null values on its properties:

```
// Defined mapped type Nullified from type T.
// Mapped type has all the same properties with the 
// same types except that the properties in Nullified
// can also be null
type Nullified<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] | null
}

function nullify<T>(arg: T): Nullified<T> {
    var returnObj = {} as Nullified<T>;

    for (var key in arg) {
        returnObj[key] = null
    }
    return returnObj
}
```